# How to get another table field information

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables, user/team/user_team(many-to-many)

```
user
-----------
id  name 
1   Tom
2   Jerry
3   John

team
------------
id   name
1    t1
2    t2
3    t3

user_team
---------------------
userid   teamid  isdeleted
1        t1       0   <----(0 means not deleted record, which can be searched out)
2        t2       1   <----(1 means deleted record, which can not be searched out)
```

I want to get all team records information with associated user information like below

```
--------------
tid tname  username
1   t1     Tom
2   t2     
3   t3
```

Can you tell me how to write the sql statement?

Sorry for my mistake. I've updated my question by adding one more record t3 in team table.

Comment: Have you tried something so far?

Comment: @ChristianMark yes, I tried to search out some information from book but I got nothing.  Could you help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: thank you so much for all of your input. I'm new to Stackoverflow, not sure if I can mark multiple responses as answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
Select a.id as tid
a.name as tname
b.name as username
from team a
LEFT JOIN user_team c on a.name = c.teamid and c.isdeleted = 0
LEFT JOIN user b on b.id = c.userid
```

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try. See a demo fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d918a/2

```
select t.id as tid,
t.name as tname,
case when ut.isdeleted = 0 then u.name else '' end as username
from team t 
left join user_team ut
on t.name = ut.teamid
left join user u
on ut.userid = u.id;
```

Which will result in

[image]

Comment: My mistake. I've updated my question by adding one more record t3 in team table, could you update your sql? With the existing sql t3 cannot be searched out.

Comment: @user2574853, you just need to do a left join instead of inner join. edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
         SELECT t.id tid, t.name tname, GROUP_CONCAT(u.name) usernames
           FROM user_team ut 
LEFT OUTER JOIN team t ON ut.teamid = t.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN user u ON ut.userid = u.id
       GROUP BY t.id;
```

To include the flag that can be searched out try this (just include a condition for flag):

```
         SELECT t.id tid, t.name tname, GROUP_CONCAT(u.name) usernames
           FROM user_team ut 
LEFT OUTER JOIN team t ON ut.teamid = t.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN user u ON ut.userid = u.id
            AND ut.isdeleted = 1 --this will add a condition for deleted teams
       GROUP BY t.id;
```

Comment: thanks for you answer, but I don't want to add function in sql statement since it may impact performance.

Comment: Yes, but the result would be more accurate. You can try it.:)

Comment: My mistake. I've updated my question by adding one more record t3 in team table, could you update your sql?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a simple `OUTER JOIN`:

```
select t.id as tid,
    t.name as tname,
    u.name as username
from team t 
    left join user_team ut on t.id = ut.teamid and ut.isdeleted = 0
    left join user u on ut.userid = u.id
```

[A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Comment: username field are displayed as null.